# Three.js CORS errors when loading image with THREE.TextureLoader()

Tags: three.js

I am getting `cors` when I try to load image from server. Normally I can load/display the image with using `img` tag but when I try to load it with `THREE.TextureLoader()`; it returns cors error.

I tried to handle it like below.

```
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

loader.setCrossOrigin("anonymous");

let texture = loader.load(src,
  function ( texture ) {},

  function ( progress ) {},
  // error drops as cors
  function ( error ) {console.log(error)});

let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture});
let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

Many answer says `crossOrigin = ""` fixes the issue but it doesn't. Is there any workaround for `cors` handling with textureloader?

Comment: Would it be possible or have you tried to include `access-control-allow-origin: *` as part of the image's response headers? It's something that you'll need to do on the server-side.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Django` and `three.js` confused me little bit. Because normally I can display image without a problem apart from `three.js`. I mean no CORS error because I am handling that with `corsheaders` module. But it's look like `three.js` doesn't care about that part. So I did a direct Allow-Origin handling inside `domain.conf`file for media directory.

```
<Directory "/var/www/domain/media">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In the end this solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> loader.setCrossOrigin("anonymous");

Since `anonymous` is the default value for `crossOrigin`, there is no need to set it explicitly.

When a CORS issue pops up in context of `TextureLoader`, you have to fix the issue on the server-side by ensuring CORS headers are properly defined. The configuration of such headers depends on your used web server.

Comment: I already fixed the issue on the server side. I can display image with `<img>` tag, but with textureLoader it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

hello if still you have this problem:
in some cases you should use you'r image path like below:

```
image_path+'?not-from-cache-please'
```

for more information check this link:
https://www.hacksoft.io/blog/handle-images-cors-error-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
textureLoader.crossOrigin = null
```